# My validation error messaged are not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to display error messages on my required fields and they are not showing. When I inspect the form it says:

> field-validation-valid

when it should be saying:

> field-validation error

I added the `jquery-val` scripts to the layout but that hasn't changed anything. The only thing I could see as an issue is I am inheriting fields from an abstract class.

For my property class (I have required for most of my fields and none of them work:

```
[Required]
public string Street { get; set; }
```

Here is field I want to validate:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertySelling.Street)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropertySelling.Street, new { @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PropertySelling.Street)
</div>
```

EDIT
This is what my controller has

```
       public ActionResult Save(PropertySelling property)
                {
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        var viewModel = new NewPropertyViewModel()
                        {
                            PropertySelling = property,
                            Sellers = _context.Sellers.ToList()
                        };
                        return View("PropertyForm", viewModel);
                    }
                    if (property.PropertySellingId == 0)
                        _context.PropertySellings.Add(property);
                    else
                    {
                        var propertyInDb = _context.PropertySellings.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PropertySellingId == property.PropertySellingId);
                        propertyInDb.Street = property.Street;
                        propertyInDb.City = property.City;
                        propertyInDb.Postcode = property.Postcode;
                        propertyInDb.Type = property.Type;
                        propertyInDb.SellingPrice = property.SellingPrice;
                        propertyInDb.ViewingStartDate = property.ViewingStartDate;
                        propertyInDb.ViewingEndDate = property.ViewingEndDate;
                        propertyInDb.NearbyAnementies = property.NearbyAnementies;
                    }

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Properties");

                }
```

An this is the message I get from inspection.[image: Inspection saying valid when it should be an error]

Comment: `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` might be what you're looking for. Also, do you check if `ModelState.IsValid` in your controller?

Comment: can you show the markup of the textbox and validition message after page renders?

Comment: I have the (!Model.IsValid) check
I want to add images and code can you do that in these comments?

Comment: I have edited my post to include controller and inspection. I tried using
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]. But it still didn't work.

Comment: Why you dont pass the viewModel to the action?  public ActionResult Save(NewPropertyViewModel vm)
                {
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        
                        return View("PropertyForm", vm);
                    } ... Then you are sure is the same properties and validations when it's whrong the sended ModelState

Comment: Your POST method does not seem to match the view - The model in the POST method is `PropertySelling`, but the model in the view does appears to be `NewPropertyViewModel` which means you code will never work (they need to be the same)